# Using keycloak as an IdP when building a Rest API - the protect() method returns HTML

Tags: node.js, typescript, keycloak, keycloak-connect

I'm trying to build a Rest API in NodeJS and I want to use Keycloak to secure it.

I'm currently using keycloak-connect from npm to integrate it.

The problem is that when an Authorization token is not attached to the Request at all, I get this page as a response in Postman and I don't want that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading &#39;keycloak-token&#39;)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at SessionStore.get (C:\Users\Laura\Desktop\supercatalog\node_modules\keycloak-connect\stores\session-store.js:24:58)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Keycloak.getGrant (C:\Users\Laura\Desktop\supercatalog\node_modules\keycloak-connect\keycloak.js:311:30)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at grantAttacher (C:\Users\Laura\Desktop\supercatalog\node_modules\keycloak-connect\middleware\grant-attacher.js:20:14)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Laura\Desktop\supercatalog\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Laura\Desktop\supercatalog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:323:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\Laura\Desktop\supercatalog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Laura\Desktop\supercatalog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:341:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\Laura\Desktop\supercatalog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at adminRequest (C:\Users\Laura\Desktop\supercatalog\node_modules\keycloak-connect\middleware\admin.js:119:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Laura\Desktop\supercatalog\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to return my own message, with my own HTTP status code (I currently get 500 internal server error).

Here's the code which triggers my error:

```
import { getKeycloak } from '../../config/keycloak-config';

let keycloak: Keycloak = getKeycloak();

router.get('/', keycloak.protect("admin"), (req:Request, res:Response):void => {
    
});
```

and here's my keycloak configuration:

```
import express, {Application} from 'express';
import { Keycloak as KeycloakType } from "keycloak-connect";

var session = require('express-session');
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');

let _keycloak: KeycloakType;

var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

let kcConfig = {
    clientId: 'rest-api',
    bearerOnly: true,
    serverUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
    realm: 'supercatalog',
    realmPublicKey: 'realm-public-key'
};

function getKeycloak() {
    if (_keycloak) {
        return _keycloak;
    } 
    console.log("Initializing Keycloak...");
    _keycloak = new Keycloak({ store: memoryStore }, kcConfig);
    return _keycloak;
}

export {getKeycloak, memoryStore};
```

When I hit that route, I get that HTML page and 500 HTTP status code.

I want to send my own status code and a JSON. (or at least make keycloak-connect send a 401/403, not a 500)

How can I do that?

Comment: Stop mixing import and require. Put everything in one file without the getkeycloak function, the way you set this up it does not work.

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann it does. I can do requests just fine - the only problem is that it gives me a 500 Internal error and HTML when there is no token set in the header.

Comment: I recommend that you study the example at https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/tree/main/example and try your scenario with that code